# Listening to the removal of single elements of an ObservableList

Tags: javafx

I have an `ObservableList<T>` of some class and I want to add a listener to an individual element of the list that should be called when the element is removed from the list. Of course I could add a change listener to the whole list, that checks whether the removed item is the correct one, but is there a more idiomatic solution to the problem, like wrapping the element in an Observable (so `ObservableList<Observable<T>>`) and adding an InvalidationListener to that Observable or something?
Thanks for your help!

Edit:
I am looking for a way to add a Listener to an ObservableList that only fires upon the removal of a specific element. As far as I can tell, fx doesn't natively provide that functionality.

Comment: to be notified of the removal from a list you have to listen to the  ... list :) The item has no knowledge of where it resides (and should not, imagine the notification mess when it is contained in several lists), so it logically can't send any notification. Anyway, sounds like a x-y-problem to me, better explain what you want to achieve (preferably with a [mcve])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a short solution using the JavaFX Bindings library:

```
BooleanBinding isContained = Bindings.isNotEmpty(list.filtered(element ->  {
    return element == elementOfInterest;
}));
isContained.addListener ((obs, oldval, newval) -> {
    // do stuff
});
```

This gives you an `Observable<Boolean> isContained` that is `true` exactly when `elementOfInterest` is contained in `list` and `false` otherwise. Listening to its changes provides the solution.

Comment: Interesting solution :)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way<sup>1</sup> for an `ObservableList` to notify listeners only when a specific element is removed. You should just add a `ListChangeListener` and react appropriately when the desired element has been removed. If you want to make a reusable class for this it could look something like:

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;

public abstract class FilteredRemoveListChangeListener<E> implements ListChangeListener<E> {

    private final Predicate<? super E> predicate;

    public FilteredRemoveListChangeListener(Predicate<? super E> predicate) {
        this.predicate = Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
    }

    @Override
    public final void onChanged(Change<? extends E> c) {
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                c.getRemoved().stream().filter(predicate).forEachOrdered(this::onRemoved);
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract void onRemoved(E element);

}
```

You may want to modify `onRemoved` to also take the source `ObservableList` (obtained via `Change.getList`) in order to do things like remove the listener if needed—something like `onRemoved(ObservableList<? extends E> list, E element)`<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1. Technically you could implement your own `ObservableList` that does this, but that's overkill compared to the listener solution above.</sup>

<sup>2. As is normal for a `ListChangeListener`, *do not modify the elements of an `ObservableList` from inside the listener*.</sup>